# Catch Exception, add data, and rethrow it

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code:

```
try
{
   OnInitialize();
}
catch (PageObjectLifecycleException exception)
{
   exception.OldLifecycleState = CurrentLifecycleState;
   exception.RequestedLifecycleState = LifecycleState.Initialized;
   throw exception;
}
```

I catch an exception, add some more data to it, and rethrow it. Resharper warns me (correctly) that a rethrow is possibly intended and suggests changing it to:

```
throw;
```

But I'm wondering: Will this correctly rethrow the **modified** exception or the unmodified original one?

**Edit**: In response to the "Try it and see" comments: I am new to C#, comming from C++. In C++ you often find undefined behaviour in corner cases like this and I am interested in whether what I want is really how it officially works.

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Comment: it will rethrow whatever the reference is pointing too - in your case the modified "exception".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will throw the reference to the modified exception.

However I am not sure whether this is good programming style. Consider creating a new exception and add the PageObjectLifecycleException as its inner exception. This way the handling code can be sure whether it has the correct additional information or not.

Comment: Me too, this a real bug hider. Outer catch block trampling on the data passed back from a deeper one for instance.

Comment: The code sample is simplified. No existing data will be overwritten, only some missing additional data is supplied.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `Exception.Data` sounds like it's supposed to be for this very purpose ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 62):

You can add the extra information into data and re-throw the exception with `throw` so it maintains its original form and the callstack

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (PageObjectLifecycleException exception)
{
   exception.Data.Add("additional data", "the additional data");
   throw;
}
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, that's what `Data` is for. As long as one guards against key conflicts, and keeps in mind that whatever information contained in the dictionary is 1) propagated up the call chain and 2) can be modified along the way, it's a great way to add useful information to ease debugging.

Comment: And one way to prevent key conflict exceptions is to use exception.Data["additional data"] = "the additional data". Yes, existing data will be overwritten but at least it won't throw a new ArgumentException which would hide the original exception.

Comment: @JustinJStark Good point, you don't need any new exception there. But since it's a collection you have to be carefull with non existing item exception. You could check if there is an existing item already with an `if`. You can be verbose there, it's error handling, not a critical path.

Comment: I went with this, but the system is telling me I need a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll.  Anybody got an idea as to why?  Just curious...

Answer (score 29):

I know the answer's already been chosen but here's a little more info on the subject.

```
try {
    // code
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

The above code when compiled into IL will produce a call to `throw` passing a reference to the handled exception as an argument.  As you are probably aware, you can call `throw` from anywhere in your code to raise an exception.

```
try {
    // code
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw;
}
```

The above code when compiled into IL will produce a call to `rethrow`.  This is different to `throw` as `rethrow` is used to signal that the block in which the exception was handled has for some reason decided not to handle it and therefore, responsibility should be offered to a higher order catch block (next one up).

The `rethrow` method *preserves* the current call stack trace so that the origin of the exception can be tracked down.  However, the `throw` method starts a new call stack trace.  I think this makes sense once you understand what the two methods are meant to be used for.

In my experience you use `throw exception;` when you want to throw an exception for some reason (e.g. validation of an object failed) and you would use `throw;` in a catch statement after you've performed some logging (i.e. while you still have access to useful information in the object that failed validation before passing exception handling responsibilities to a higher level).

In your example I would suggest that if you need to add more information to an exception you have a case for creating an entirely new exception and raising it.  So you would use the `throw exception;` method where "exception" is a new exception containing the extra information and the originally thrown exception.

Hope that helps!

James

Answer (score 2):

The current exception is re-thrown, although I'm not sure your pattern is a very nice and maintainable one.